# How to be notified when a UINavigation is dismissed using protocols?

Tags: swift, protocols, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working on a simple UI Kit based game using swift, some of the pages will fire a modal or another page; when this page is complete it returns to the calling page.

What I'd like to know is how do I notify or watch or otherwise listen for it's return so I can do some actions.

For example.

1. Game has 3 players
2. Page with modal dialog. A user does an action on this modal
3. Dialog is dismissed and returns with some changes
4. The launching page now moves to the next player on turn, or if there are no more players on turn; go to the next segue.

I believe its possible to do it using Protocols?

So what I'm wanting is to listen for the UINavigation to return to my launching page and do some actions.

But how do I do this using Swift?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can use **closures** in swift.

Refer to : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

When you are presenting the second controller, you can set a `closure` as a property of second controller. Now when you dismiss the second controller, you can call this closure in second controller's dismiss block.

**Example:**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController
{
    func presentSecondController()
    {
        let secondController = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
        secondController.completionClosure = {
            //Write your code here that you want to execute on FirstViewController when secondController is dismissed
        }
        self.present(secondController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController
{
    var completionClosure : (()->())?

    func dismissController()
    {
        self.dismiss(animated: true) { 
            if let closure = self.completionClosure
            {
                closure()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I do things like: When page is closed: (a) Go to next player on turn (b) that player makes a move or it goes to the next page

Comment: Many thanks; found some tuts on youtube and another answer  on stack overflow -> http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/434/passing-data-between-view-controllers#t=201703071155554178066